# Weakest theory over which "all sets are measurable" has consistency strength?

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

Some convention: $\textrm{DC}$ stands for axiom of dependent choice, $\text{LM}$ stands for the statement "all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Lebesgue measurable", $\textrm{IC}$ for "there exists an inaccessible cardinal", and $\textrm{BZ}$ for bounded Zermelo, i.e., no replacement and comprehension is restricted to bounded formulas.

A well-known result of Solovay and Shelah says $\textrm{ZF}+\textrm{DC}+\text{LM}$ is equiconsistent with $\textrm{ZFC}+\textrm{IC}$. François G. Dorais explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141801/how-strong-is-all-sets-are-lebesgue-measurable-in-weaker-contexts-than-zf) that Shelah's proof can be adapted to show that $\textrm{BZ}+\textrm{DC}+\text{LM}$ proves the consistency of $\textrm{ZFC}$ (indeed the existence of a well-founded model, so $\textrm{ZFC}$ is sound in a strong sense).

My question: is there a (natural) theory weaker than $\textrm{BZ}+\textrm{DC}$ such that adding $\text{LM}$ to it increases the consistency strength? I am particularly interested in constructive/predicative mathematics; I don't really know much about them, so to me constructive and predicative sounds more or less the same, and could mean anything like $\textrm{CZF}$, $\textrm{IZF}$, $\textrm{IKP}$, Nik Weaver's conceptualism, various structural set theories, etc. (I don't know if $\text{LM}$ makes sense in subsystems of second order arithmetic; also incidentally $\textrm{ETCS}$ is equiconsistent with $\textrm{BZ}+\textrm{AC}$). The motivation is that since all non-measurable sets we know are highly non-constructive, it seems reasonable to adopt $\text{LM}$ in constructive mathematics, and it will be interesting if this turns out to justify something non-constructive like $\textrm{ZFC}$.

Comment: Predicative mathematics usually means mathematics without the power set axiom; while constructive mathematics usually means mathematics without excluded middle.

Comment: In predicative classical mathematics, one cannot have exponentiation or subset collection since with excluded middle both imply power sets. However, in predicative constructive mathematics, the lack of excluded middle means both exponentiation and subset collection are strictly weaker than power sets, one could include either axiom in constructive mathematics while still remaining in predicative mathematics.

Comment: While the axiom of choice proper implies excluded middle, certain branches of constructive mathematics do accept weaker forms of choice, such as countable choice or dependent choice, as they do not imply excluded middle and are necessary to ensure that the various definitions of the real numbers result in the same set. Otherwise, without countable choice, one has to distinguish between different sets of real numbers like Cantor real numbers, Cauchy real numbers, Dedekind real numbers, and select one of them to use in the LM axiom.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield I know the issue with choice in constructive math. Does DC suffice for a nice Lebesgue measure theory in constructive math?

Comment: That I don't know the answer to, since I don't work with dependent choice in my constructive mathematics. 

My personal interest in this question would lie in how much choice could one get rid of from the original model in question; i.e. BZ + countable choice + LM, or BZ + LM, at extreme assume the real numbers are Dedekind real numbers in IBZ + LM; IBZ being the constructive version of BZ.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield With absolutely no choice we also need to be careful about the definition of measurable sets, since e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ could be a countable union of countable sets. I know that DC suffices for most purposes in classical logic, not sure about intuitionistic logic

Comment: There is also the locale of real numbers, which coincides with the Dedekind real numbers with excluded middle, but which in general in constructive mathematics is different from the Dedekind real numbers. I don't know if DC is enough to ensure that the locale of real numbers coincides with the Dedekind real numbers.

Comment: Minor point: IZF already has the same consistency strength as ZFC.

Answer (score 6):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but I think it's an important point to make. Also, as I discuss at the end it is *technically* an answer.

You are never going to have a constructively acceptable theory in which all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable (in the sense of having a Lebesgue measure that is a Dedekind real number), because this implies the weak law of excluded middle (i.e., $\neg \varphi \vee \neg\neg\varphi$).

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the Dedekind reals, and let $\mathbb{R}^+$ be the extended Dedekind reals.

> **Proposition 1.**  Assume that there is a function $\lambda : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying that $\lambda(\varnothing) = 0$ and $\lambda([0,1]) = 1$. Then the weak law of excluded middle holds.

*Proof.* Fix a statement $\varphi$ and consider the set $X = \{x \in [0,1] : \varphi\}$. Since $\lambda(X)$ is a Dedekind real, we have that either $\lambda(X) < \frac{2}{3}$ or $\lambda(X) > \frac{1}{3}$.

If $\lambda(X) < \frac{2}{3}$, assume for the sake of contradiction (which is fine because we're proving a negative) that $\varphi$ holds. We then have that $X = [0,1]$, so $\lambda(X) = 1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $\neg \varphi$ holds.

If $\lambda(X) > \frac{1}{3}$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $\neg \varphi$ holds. We then have that $X = \varnothing$, so $\lambda(X) = 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $\neg\neg\varphi$ holds.

So we have $\neg \varphi \vee \neg\neg \varphi$. Since we can do this for any $\varphi$, $\mathsf{WLEM}$ holds. $\square$

I think it's likely that the assumption of Proposition 1 implies $\mathsf{LEM}$, but I don't see an argument right now. If we assume slightly more, namely that positive measure sets are inhabited (i.e., have elements), then we actually get $\mathsf{LEM}$ fully.

> **Proposition 2.** Assume that there is a function $\lambda : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying that $\lambda(\varnothing) = 0$, $\lambda([0,1]) = 1$, and if $\lambda(X) > 0$, then $X$ is inhabited. Then the law of excluded middle holds.

*Proof.* Fix $\varphi$ and let $X$ be as before. If $\lambda(X) < \frac{2}{3}$, then we have $\neg \varphi$ again. If $\lambda(X) > \frac{1}{3}$, then $\lambda(X) > 0$, so there is an $x \in X$. By definition this implies that $\varphi$ holds. Therefore $\varphi \vee \neg \varphi$. Since we can do this for any $\varphi$, $\mathsf{LEM}$ holds. $\square$

One might argue that the assumption in Proposition 2 is too strong, but actually this principle (that positive measure sets are inhabited) is an important technical point in Bishop and Cheng's approach to constructive measure theory, so I don't think it's necessarily a ridiculous thing to ask of positive measure sets.

Note that this really has very little to do with measure theory. By the same token, it's not even constructively acceptable to assume that every subset of $\{0\}$ is 'counting-measurable' either (i.e., has a cardinality that is a natural number).

---

Anyway, the technical sense in which this answers your question is as follows: $\mathsf{CZF} + \mathsf{LEM}$ is $\mathsf{ZF}$ and the consistency strength of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (equivalently $\mathsf{ZFC}$) is much higher than that of $\mathsf{CZF}$ (which is comparable to $\mathsf{KP}$). I do not know anything about the consistency strength of $\mathsf{CZF} + \mathsf{WLEM}$, but if I had to bet, I would say it's probably the same as $\mathsf{ZF}$ too, since it feels like $\mathsf{WLEM}$ should make a double negation translation easier.